# $ X=C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $||f||=\max\{||f||_{\infty}, ||f'||_{\infty}\}$ form a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that the space $X=C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ of the functions in
>   $[0,1]$ to real values with continuous derivative and with the norm
>   $||f||=\max\{||f||_{\infty}, ||f'||_{\infty}\}$ is a Banach space. Is
>   $(X, ||.||_{\infty})$ Banach?

I'm assuming $||f||$ as defined is already a norm. Then I just need to show that every Cauchy sequence is convergent. However, I don't know how to assume a general Cauchy Sequence. A sequence of functions can have any face. So I think another theorem must be used instead. Maybe something that talks about another definition equivalent to this one, that doesn't involve cauchy sequences. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{f_n\}$ be Cauchy. Then there exist continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f_n' \to g$ uniformly. Now $f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_o^{x} f_n'(t)\, dt$. Let $n \to \infty$ to see that $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} g(t)\, dt$. This implies that $f$ is differentiable and $f'=g$. Hence $f \in C^{1}[0,1])$ and it is clear that $f_n \to f$ in the given norm.

Answer (score 1):

A Cauchy Sequence with respect to this metric implies uniform convergence and the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, so the sequence of functions converges to a continuous function. Their derivatives also converge to a continuous function, so then the sequences all converge in $C^1([0,1];\mathbb{R})$. It remains to show that $\lim f_n'(x)=f'(x)$. Or as suggested by the next answer. Be careful, if you use the proof bellow you need to justify the passage of the limit through the integral.

Comment: You still need to show that the uniform limit is also differentiable.

Comment: Well, what I need is to show that the limit of the derivatives is the derivative of the limit. Which is not difficult. To be specific one needs to show that if $\{f_n\}$, is Cauchy then, $f_n(x+\frac{1}{n})$ is also Cauchy. I have a feeling this is for homework that is why I am holding back on the details.

Comment: I didn't mean to say it's difficult or doesn't work, I just wanted to point out that one major step of the proof was not yet covered by your hint.

Comment: Thanks, @MarsPlastic! I think OP has gone radio silent.